# Hierarchical queries in MySQL with Right Left Groups

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical

I have a table with 2 columns username and leader

```
  login_user    sponsered_id  right_left
    test1       admin          Right
    test2       admin          Left
    test3       test1          Right
    test4       test1          Left
    test43      test2          Left
    test44      test3          Left
```

I have a function

```
function display_children($parent, $level) { 

    // retrieve all children of $parent 

    $result = mysql_query('SELECT name, login_user, right_left FROM members_list '. 

                           'WHERE sponsered_id="'.$parent.'";'); 


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

        // indent and display the title of this child 


     echo '<tr><td>'.
   $row['login_user'].' </td><td> '.$row['right_left'].' </td><td> '.$row['sponsered_id'].
    "</td></tr>";  


        // call this function again to display this 

        // child's children 

        display_children($row['login_user'], $level+1); 

    } 

} 

echo display_children('admin',0);
```

But not getting right output .... its giving me output

```
test1   Right   admin
test3   Right   test1
test44  Left    test3
test4   Right   test1
test2   Left    admin
test43  Left    test2
```

need output as

```
test1   Right   admin
test2   Left    admin

test3   Right   test1
test4   Left    test1

        Right   test2
test43  Left    test2

        Right   test3
test44  Left    test3
```

Comment: The output you stated doens't match the values in the database:
`Right   test2` doens't exist. I think you should just order them by login_user, and you should get pretty close to the output you stated.

Comment: I guess as Kao suggested, sorting your resultset may give you a more desirable output.
Also, I wouldl ike to recommend using Nested Set model hierarichal data, it's much more easy to work with and traverse trough nodes and branches in your hierarchy.

Comment: @Kao thats wt my question is some value is not in Right Or Left, it should display blank ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    login_user,
    right_left, 
    sponsered_id  
FROM (
    SELECT 
        login_user,
        right_left, 
        sponsered_id  
    FROM 
        members_list

    UNION

    SELECT 
        NULL,
        CASE when max(right_left) ='Left' THEN 'Right' ELSE 'Left' END AS right_left, 
        sponsered_id
    FROM 
        members_list  
    GROUP BY 
        sponsered_id
    HAVING count(sponsered_id) < 2
) as temp
ORDER BY
    sponsered_id, 
    right_left
```

Comment: thx its worked ... but can i use WHERE sponsered_id= with this as i need output according to sponsered_id ??

Comment: @Harinder, Sure, you can add it in the outermost where clauses

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
   select login_user , right_left , sponsered_id  from (

   select login_user , right_left , sponsered_id 
    from members_list
   union all

    select login_user , if(right_left ='left', 'right', 'right' ) right_left ,  sponsered_id
   from members_list 

  )t
  group by sponsered_id, right_left
  order by login_user
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20a50/38)

Comment: thx for reply .... but its giveing wrong output as u can see there is no right on test2 and no right on test3 but demo is giving wrong output for both ;(

Comment: wrong output? is exacly like yours. yes test2 have no right and it doesnt show right , it shows left . i dont understand what u mean

Comment: if u see test43 is coming in both right and left ... this is wrong because 'Right   test2' is blank so it should show blank there